# How can I make a form with custom check boxes that will direct me to different html files on submit form?

Tags: javascript, html, uwp

I have a form with custom check boxes that I want to hold references to my other html pages. I want the user to select one of the check boxes and then hit the start button at the bottom. What should happen is it will take the user to the html file that was attached to the checkbox. I know this probably didnt make sense so go to the [web](https://cartcoin2--liamstelly-hawk.repl.co/problems) version of the site to get an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
    <form method="post">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="media">
                <img src="https://www.mometrix.com/academy/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Algebra-I-1024x683.jpg" class="mr-3" alt="" width="150" height="150">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Algebra</h5>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" name="AL">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="media">
                <img src="https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/a/ae/Find-Area-and-Perimeter-Step-7-Version-2.jpg/aid3987529-v4-728px-Find-Area-and-Perimeter-Step-7-Version-2.jpg" class="mr-3" alt="..." width="150" height="150">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Area &amp; Perimeter</h5>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch2" name="AP">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="media">
                <img src="https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/images/arithmetic.svg" class="mr-3" alt="..." width="150" height="150">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Arithmetic</h5>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch3" name="AR">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch3"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="media">
                <img src="https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/images/exponent-8-2.svg" class="mr-3" alt="..." width="150" height="150">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Exponents</h5>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch4" name="EX">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch4"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="media">
                <img src="https://dmzn2b8hkpq8b.cloudfront.net/images/products/515x515/S411589.jpg" class="mr-3" alt="..." width="150" height="150">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Geometric Solids</h5>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch5" name="GS">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch5"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="media">
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="mr-3" alt="..." width="150" height="150">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Probability</h5>
                    <div class="">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch6" name="PR">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch6"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="media">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDvygQLpB_G08iwALHg6N6rIEm1abgLnEQKZF0Qn6QOZFQDYWP" class="mr-3" alt="..." width="150" height="150">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Systems of Equations</h5>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch7" name="SE">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch7"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="media">
                <img src="http://home.windstream.net/okrebs/Ch8-28.gif" class="mr-3" alt="..." width="150" height="150">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Trig Statements</h5>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch8" name="TR">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch8"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        </div>
    </div>
    <center>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Start</button>
    </center>
</form>
```

Comment: Listen to the submit event, prevent the default, change the window location to that of the attribute.

Comment: @TinyGiant Not sure I follow.

Comment: and if several checkboxes are checked, what is the page to choose?

Comment: @MisterJojo It wont do anything. I will make it so more than one cant be chosen later

Answer (score 0):

I made some minor changes
1 _ adding **data-page** to each checkbox with page url.
2 _ addind **ID** to the form

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
  const
    MyForm       = document.getElementById('My-Form'),
    all_checkBox = document.querySelectorAll('#My-Form input[type=checkbox]'),
    SubmitBt     = document.querySelector('#My-Form button[type=submit]');

  all_checkBox.forEach(chkBx=>{ chkBx.onchange = ChkBxChanged })

  SubmitBt.disabled = true;

  function ChkBxChanged(e)
  {
    MyForm.action = '';
    SubmitBt.disabled = true;

    if ( this.checked )
    {
      MyForm.action     = this.dataset.page;
      SubmitBt.disabled = false;

      all_checkBox.forEach(cb=>{
        if (cb!=this) cb.checked = false   // only one should be checked
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="My-Form" action="" method="POST" >

  <h5 class="mt-0">Algebra</h5>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" name="AL" data-page="Algebra.html" >

  <h5 class="mt-0">Area &amp; Perimeter</h5>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch2" name="AP" data-page="Area_Perimeter.html" >

  <h5 class="mt-0">Arithmetic</h5>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch3" name="AR" data-page="Arithmetic.html" >

  <h5 class="mt-0">Exponents</h5>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch4" name="EX" data-page="Exponents.html" >

  <h5 class="mt-0">Geometric Solids</h5>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch5" name="GS" data-page="Geometric_Solids.html" >

  <h5 class="mt-0">Probability</h5>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch6" name="PR" data-page="Probability.html" >

  <h5 class="mt-0">Systems of Equations</h5>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch7" name="SE" data-page="Equations.html" >

  <h5 class="mt-0">Trig Statements</h5>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch8" name="TR" data-page="Trig_Statements.html" >

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Start</button>

</form>
```

Comment: It just gives me a white screen when i reidrect it. I also had to make a few changes.

Comment: see the new url of your new page, they corresonding of  in data-page value, you have to change it for yours

Comment: I saw, but there is no checkbox

Comment: what about  <input type="**checkbox**" class="custom-control-input"...? they are what ?

Comment: you have to change **data-page** value on each one  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: I forgot to mention I am making this for my UWP JavaScript app. I will post what I have so far on an answer.

Comment: it just wont work. I am thinking of just assigning link to page and onclick

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done with the code you gave me Mister Jojo

```
    <script>

    const
        MyForm = document.getElementById('My-Form'),
        all_checkBox = document.querySelectorAll('#My-Form input[type=checkbox]'),
        SubmitBt = document.querySelector('#My-Form button[type=submit]');

    all_checkBox.forEach(chkBx => { chkBx.onchange = ChkBxChanged })

    SubmitBt.disabled = true;

    function ChkBxChanged(e) {
        MyForm.action = '';
        SubmitBt.disabled = true;

        if (this.checked) {
            MyForm.action = this.dataset.page;
            SubmitBt.disabled = false;

            all_checkBox.forEach(cb => {
                if (cb != this) cb.checked = false   // only one should be checked
            })
        }
    }
</script>
<form id="My-Form" action="" method="POST">

    <h5 class="mt-0">Algebra</h5>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" name="AL" data-page="index.html">

    <h5 class="mt-0">Area &amp; Perimeter</h5>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch2" name="AP" data-page="index.html">

    <h5 class="mt-0">Arithmetic</h5>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch3" name="AR" data-page="index.html">

    <h5 class="mt-0">Exponents</h5>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch4" name="EX" data-page="index.html">

    <h5 class="mt-0">Geometric Solids</h5>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch5" name="GS" data-page="index.html">

    <h5 class="mt-0">Probability</h5>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch6" name="PR" data-page="index.html">

    <h5 class="mt-0">Systems of Equations</h5>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch8" name="SE" data-page="index.html">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Start</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Ok, I see, you have placed the script before the form element....
the script must be placed **AFTER**   ( and just befor the end body tag `</body>`  or you have to use  DOMContentLoaded event. => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event )

Comment: so did you do it ?

Comment: what are console error ? ? ( on **FireFox** use F12 and see **Console**)

Comment: I have changed my answer by adding `ocument.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",...`  just saying that it does not work is not constructive